# Url change when i do a ajax call

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I have a problem with url.
In a system, I display some user info, url is: showUserInfo.
I can click on a button, it show a dialog and allow to create a new user. 
I do a ajax call: createUser.

My problem is when I do this call, the url change in the url dialog, if I refresh the page, some problems appears, because we have the createUser url but with showUserInfo.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/showUserInfo")
public String userView(Model model, Locale locale) {
    model.addAttribute("userList", userBeanMap);

    model.addAttribute("userBeanForm", new UserBeanForm());

    return userView;
}


@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/createUser")
public String createUser(Model model, @ModelAttribute UserBeanForm userBeanForm, BindingResult result) {
  ...
  ...
}


$('#createUser').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 660,
    width: 715,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        Save: function() {
                $('#addUserForm').submit();
            }
        },
        Cancel: function() {
            $('#addUserForm').trigger("reset");
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    },
    close: function() {
        $('#addUserForm').trigger("reset");
    }
 });

 <form:form id="#addUserForm" action="${addUserUrl}" modelAttribute="userBeanForm">
  ...
 </form>
```

Is there a way to avoid this behavior?

Comment: It is a bit difficult to understand what's actually going on. Can you paste some code so we can help you better?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you're asking, so clarification would be helpful. Particularly, what do you mean when you say:
"if I refresh the page, some problems appears, because we have the createUser url but with showUserInfo."

What is the problem that you are seeing? I'm going to take a you want to avoid double posting, so using a PRG pattern may solve your issue:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

However, if you're doing an AJAX call, this shouldn't be the case. If you want to avoid a refresh after the submit, can you instead of calling the form's submit, do something like this?

```
Save: function() {
           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "/createUser",
               data: $("#addUserForm").serialize(),
               success: function(data)
               {
                   // javascript to update page
               }
            });
        }
    },
```

More information on JQuery ajax: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
If the post is supposed to update something you can return a json on the server side, and have the javascript success function parse it and update the page accordingly.

If you actually want the refresh to occur, then:
Is the "/createUser" url returning something different from the get? If not, you can change the post handler to return a redirect to the GET page:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/createUser")
public String createUser(Model model, @ModelAttribute UserBeanForm userBeanForm, BindingResult result) {
    ...
    ...
    return "redirect:/showUserInfo"
}
```

If you want to store some data created by the post and are using Spring 3.1, look into flash attributes:
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-flash-attributes

You can change your post handler such, and adjust your get handler to somehow use that data or pass it on to the view:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/createUser")
public String createUser(Model model, @ModelAttribute UserBeanForm userBeanForm, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    ...
    ...
    // add data for get handler to use
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("someString", "stringValue");
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("someInt", 10);

    return "redirect:/showUserInfo"
}
```

I didn't get a chance to actually test this, but hopefully it works.